# Apply gradient to a path made of 2 paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

As you can see in the pic, I drew a Rectangle with no fill and black stroke. Then I added a curvy shape. I want to add a gradient to the place bound by those two shapes. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Live paint tool can help you

Comment: how can I use it?

Comment: http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cc/live-paint-2/